# How to use onSavedInstance cleanly?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-viewpager, android-lifecycle

I have developed an android application and it uses `ViewPager`. Everything works fine in normal scenarios (pause,resume,exit,restart). However, when application gets killed in the background by the OS, the problem crops up.

In normal flow, i initialize the view pager only after all data has been fetched.

However, in this special case, the last viewed fragment gets recreated by the OS - `onCreate()` gets called, but for successful creation, the fragment needs the data which has not yet fetched from server and thus the app crashes.

A solution is store all that variables/data in the bundle and resume from them but there are so many such variables and i feel it would be a bad design to store all of them.

How to solve this problem?

**Edit:**  my code:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //other initialization code
        getData();
        //remaining code
    }

    protected DataWrapper dataWrapper;

    private void getData(){
    try {
        //url for fetching data 
        String url = "http://....."
        new FetchAndPopulateMarketDataAsyncTask(this){
            @Override public void onPostExecute(DataWrapper result)
            {
                if(result==null){
                    //server or no internet error 
                }
                else{
                    dataWrapper = (DataWrapper)result;
                }
            }
        }.execute(new URL(url));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple serializable object which stores your necessary data in it. Then you can store this serializable in the bundle.

I dont know if this a good solution. Another solution with less code I cannot find right now.

Comment: Thanks but every time i add a new variable in code for some reason, i will have to get it serialized. This would make the code highly unmanageable.

Comment: Could you provide some code please so that I can take a look at it?

Comment: For now, I have solved the problem by not using the bundle so that activity is freshly created every time.